# February 2022 Writing Challenge: Tell a story with a terminal log

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by popular vote, the challenge this month is:

> ### Tell a story with a terminal log.
>
> Somebody is poking through a computer through the terminal. Try to tell what they're after and who they are by what they're looking at.
>
> Maybe it's somebody trying to track down their father who disappeared and was presumed dead, and so hacked into a government server. Perhaps somebody is trying to expose the SCP Foundation and is gathering information to pass on to the public.
>
> Take a bunch of creative liberties and create your terminal log. Who knows what file you'll dig up next.

Thanks goes to [Ceramicmrno0b](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/46506/ceramicmrno0b) for coming up with the prompt.

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question.

You can also vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)

Answer (score 8):

**[ STARGAZER OS BOOT PROCEDURE INITIATED ]**

Emergency system restart initiated. Power restored.

~ Booting...

**OS:** Bluemoon StargazerOS x86_64
**Host System:** MDK2J3L23BUS_TX Asukari LunarLander S13
**LunarIP:** 8238.23Y44.09872.138AA
**Lunar Coordinates:** 872'302'2427&AH2UOxo'121 SE -- *WARNING: System corruption detected. Coordinates may not be accurate.*
**Timestamp:** 05/27/UY-2091 (Universal Time) -- *WARNING: System corruption detected. Timestamp may not be accurate.*

~ Performing system check...

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Low oxygen level detected (12%).
**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Hull damage detected. Unable to estimate severity. Manual check required.
**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Uplink lost. Communications array damage detected. Please perform network diagnostics.
**[!] CRITICAL SYSTEM WARNING: Oxygen leak detected. Estimated time remaining: 30 minutes.**

System check complete. Critical maintenance required. Please reference maintenance procedures in order of severity. Please do not attempt to leave the vehicle without performing appropriate maintenance procedures.

~ Performing biometric crew scan...

**[!] BIOMETRIC WARNING:** Unable to verify biometric data for crew members:

~~ **HUTCHINSON, DAVID.** (0 BPM)
~~ **GARCIA, MELINA.** (0 BPM)
~~ **CHRISTOFFER, JAKKOB.** (0 BPM)
~~ **ORSEN, BAILEY.** (0 BPM)

Biometric crew scan complete. Biometric data was successfully detected for crew members:

~~ **JANSSEN, AMELIA.** (85 BPM)

~ Performing equipment check...

**SYSTEM NOTICE:** Foreign objects are present in the airlock. Please be advised that leaving foreign objects in the airlock may result in injury to exiting astronauts.
**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** The following mission objects have been removed from storage without being logged. Please verify the location of the missing objects.
~ FIRE EXTINGUISHMENT DEVICE (2)
~ FIRST AID KIT (1)
~ PERSONAL STORAGE BIN: BAILEY
~ PERSONAL STORAGE BIN: CHRISTOFFER
~ PERSONAL STORAGE BIN: GARCIA
~ PERSONAL STORAGE BIN: HUTCHINSON
~ STORAGE-BIN A (4)

~ Scanning for system file corruption...

**SYSTEM NOTICE:** 128 corrupted files found.

~ Repairing corrupted data files...

82% restoration complete. Some restored files were unable to be recovered fully. Please check logs.

~ Loading user interface...
~ Loading administrative profile...

**[ WELCOME TO STARGAZER OS ]**

```
                     _  _     ____________.--.
                  |\|_|//_.-"" .'    \   /|  |
                  |.-"""-.|   /       \_/ |  |
                  \  ||  /| __\_____________ |
                  _\_||_/_| .-""            ""-.  __
                .' '.    \//                    ".\/
                ||   '. >()_                     |()<
                ||__.-' |/\ \                    |/\
                   |   / "|  \__________________/.""
                  /   //  | / \ "-.__________/  /\
               ___|__/_|__|/___\___".______//__/__\
              /|\     [____________] \__/         |\
             //\ \     |  |=====| |   /\\         |\\
            // |\ \    |  |=====| |   | \\        | \\        ____...
          .//__| \ \   |  |=====| |   | |\\       |--\\---""""     . 
_____....-//___|  \_\  |  |=====| |   |_|_\\      |___\\    .       
 .      .//-.__|_______|__|_____|_|_____[__\\_____|__.-\\      .    
        //        //        /          \ `-_\\/         \\         
  -... //     .  / /       /____________\    \\       .  \ \     . 
      //   .. .-/_/-.                 .       \\        .-\_\-.    
     / /      '-----'           .             \ \      '._____.'  
  .-/_/-.         .                          .-\_\-.             
 '._____.'                            .     '._____.'             
        .
```

**Username:** sg-sergeant-amelia
**Password:** ***************

~ Access granted to [sg-sergeant-amelia@stargazer-desktop].
~ Biometrics verified. Heart rate nominal (87 BPM).

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** System instability detected due to presence of corrupted files. Please proceed with caution.

Please enter a command:
~$ directorylist

Current directory: /home
Sub-directories: /admin /bin /data /data-bin /network /sys /usr /var

Please enter a command:
~$ changedirectory network

Current directory has changed to: /home/network

Please enter a command:
~$ filelist

Files in /home/network:
~ README.txt - Text Document - 28 KB
~ SYSGUIDE.txt - Text Document - 782 KB
~ netshell-2.3.1.exe - Application - 28,173 KB

Please enter a command:
~$ execute netshell-2.3.1.exe

**SYSTEM NOTICE:** This action is an administrative action. Please re-verify administrative credentials.

**Username:** sg-sergeant-amelia
**Administrative password:** ***************

Credentials verified.
Executing netshell-2.3.1.exe...

Pinging from LunarIP 8238.23Y44.09872.138AA to EarthIP 1627.81M11.78271.316AA...
Awaiting packet response...
Awaiting packet response... (x2)

No packet response detected. Pinged system failed to respond. Error code: 787-19.

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (10%). Please take immediate action.

Please enter a command:
~$ christ please help me

**ERROR:** "christ please help me" is not a valid command. Please try again.

Please enter a command:
~$ execute netshell-2.3.1.exe -parameter response_wait_time:3000

**SYSTEM NOTICE:** This action is an administrative action. Please re-verify administrative credentials.

**Username:** sg-sergeant-amelia
**Administrative password:** ***************

Credentials verified.
Executing netshell-2.3.1.exe...

Pinging from LunarIP 8238.23Y44.09872.138AA to EarthIP 1627.81M11.78271.316AA...
Awaiting packet response...
Awaiting packet response... (x2)
Awaiting packet response... (x3)

No packet response detected. Pinged system failed to respond. Error code: 787-19.

Please enter a command:
~$

**Timeout warning:** User inaction of over 5 minutes detected. Please take action soon or you will be logged out.

Please enter a command:
~$

**BIOMETRIC WARNING:** Unusual change in neurological activity detected. Please verify readings and undergo a psychological check before further interacting with machinery.

Please enter a command:
~$ please

**ERROR:** "please" is not a valid command. Please try again.

Please enter a command:
~$

**Timeout warning:** User inaction of over 5 minutes detected. Please take action soon or you will be logged out.

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (7%). Please take immediate action.

Please enter a command:
~$ i don't know what to do

**ERROR:** "i don't know what to do" is not a valid command. Please try again.

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (6%). Please take immediate action.

Please enter a command:
~$ exitdirectory

Current directory has changed to: /home

Please enter a command:
~$ newfile -name "note.txt" -contents ""

New file created: "note.txt"

Please enter a command:
~$ texteditor "note.txt"

**[[--TEXT EDITOR--]]**

**[[Editing file: note.txt]]**

```
+ God, save my soul.
```

**[[File closed.]]**

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (5%). Please take immediate action.

Please enter a command:
~$

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (4%). Please take immediate action.

Please enter a command:
~$

**[!] SYSTEM WARNING:** Critically low oxygen level detected (3%). Please take immediate action.

**[!] SYSTEM OVERRIDE WARNING:** Airlock locking mechanism manually disabled. Please do not attempt to open doors while atmosphere is sealed.
**SYSTEM NOTIFICATION:** Airlock door opened.

**ERROR:** Biometrics measurements lost. Heart rate could not be verified.

Comment: Nitpick: dates should be in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. :-P

Answer (score 4):

```
john@thejones:~/Documents/ $ echo 'I think I guessed your password. Love, Claire.' |
> mail -s 'I hope all is well at the conference with Gina.' johnjones@thejones.com -- 
> -r "you_cheated_on_me@thejones.com" -F "your wife"
john@thejones:~/Documents/ $ sudo rm -rf /
```

Answer (score 3):

2/3/2022
1:35:22 [Power on]
1:35:24 [Loading systems...]
1:35:25 [Accessing terminal...]
1:35:25 [Please login to your account to continue]
1:35:28 Username: [Redacted]
1:35:30 Password: Password
1:35:31 [Password accepted]
1:35:31 [Access granted]
1:35:31 [Loading terminal...]
1:35:35 [Terminal loaded]
1:35:35 [What would you like to do?]
1:35:42 ~file home/programs/alphastar
1:35:42 [That file is only available to accounts with Deepmind authorization]
1:35:47 ~set-authorization; [Redacted], Deepmind
1:35:47 [Updating authorization records...]
1:35:48 [Congratulations, [Redacted], you know have Deepmind authorization]
1:36:01 ~file home/programs/alphastar/terran
1:36:01 [Loading file...]
1:36:02 [File loaded]
1:36:04 ~edit
1:36:04 [You are now editing the file]
2:12:26 ~save
2:12:27 [File saved]
2:12:27 [What would you like to do?]
2:18:04 ~run home/programs/hacking_scripts/Boston_Dynamics
2:18:04 [Password required to run this program]
2:18:06 Password: 1111
2:18:06 [Incorrect]
2:18:09 Password: 1234
2:18:09 [Incorrect]
2:18:13 Password: Incorrect
2:18:13 [Incorrect]
2:18:13 [Hint: -*-]

2:18:17 Password: ^*^
2:18:17 [Access granted]
2:18:17 [Running program...]
2:34:58 [Program complete]
2:35:11 ~cut home/programs/alphastar/terran
2:35:12 [File cut to clipboard]
2:35:19 ~access Boston_Dynamics_file_system
2:35:19 [Changing terminals...]
2:36:22 -Welcome to Boston Dynamics file system!-
2:36:28 ~delete home/robot_scripts/behavior
2:36:28 -Are you sure you want to do this?-
2:36:29 [Y]/N
2:36:29 -Deleting file...-
2:36:30 -File deleted-
2:36:34 ~paste home/robot_scripts/behavior
2:36:34 -You want to move "home/programs/alphastar/terran" to "home/robot_scripts", correct?
2:36:35 [Y]/N
2:36:35 -Moving file...-
2:36:36 -File moved-
2:36:39 ~update all_units
2:36:40 -Updating all robots...-
3:04:59 -Update distributed-
3:05:02 ~lock access: all
3:05:02 -Locking all access...-
3:05:05 -Boston Dynamics file system has been locked, please contact your administrator if you think there has been a mistake-
3:05:07 ~leave
3:05:07 [Welcome to the Terminal]
3:05:07 [What would you like to do?]
3:05:10 ~channel "news"
3:05:10 [Opening news channel]
3:05:13 ~run home/assist/speech-to-text
3:05:13 [Running Program...]
Reporter 1: All Boston Dynamics robots have begun construction of a mystery domed building and are harvesting geodes from various places. Reports have also come in from Iceland that they are building structures over steam vents. The purpose of this is unknown, and there seem to be eight distinct groups doing this.
Reporter 2: Oh look, they finished the dome and now they are building another structure. And I think they're painting themselves too, that one wasn't orange a while ago.
Reporter 1: Hey, that one's green. Is there a difference in them? 
Reporter 2: Oh. Well folks, it seems that, uh, green and orange do not get along well.
Reporter 1: That one's a lot different, I didn't know Boston Dynamics had one of those.
Reporter 2: Oh hey, I recognize that. It's from one of those E-sports things I did a story on a while ago. Star-something, they called that one an SUV, I think.
Reporter 1: Wait, did that second building spit something out?
Reporter 2: It looks like the Atlas robot. Except it's got power armor and an assault rifle?
Reported 1: Uh, we'll be right back after this break.
Spokesperson: Struggling with
3:07:13 ~stop
3:07:13 [Program ended]
6/15/2022
24:00:00 [Power loss detected]
24:00:00 [Shutting down...]

---

And that is my submission, in which the unknown deaf person makes Boston Dynamics robots play StarCraft around the world. Lucky for us, AlphaStar doesn't work nukes into the strategy very often, so we're probably okay.

Plus the world could benefit from Battlecruiser technology, so silver lining there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Username: root
Password: **********

--

Welcome back to StakExOS
Last Login at 2.13.22 23:42
Current Time: 2.14.22 09:24

 $ check_login last
The last login was over ssh by 73.138.32.5
There were 69,420 failed password attempts
Use “history --last” to see the terminal log

 $ history --last
=== BEGIN TERMINAL LOG ===
Username: root
Password: “$(passcrack6)”
 => Passcrack 6 activated ~ hacker license
 => Brute-forcing password... (69,419 passwords checked)
 => Password successfully cracked (1 min 9.42 sec)

--

Welcome back to StakExOS
Last Login at 2.13.22 12:16
Current Time: 2.13.22 23:42

 $ curl 73.138.32.5/a.txt > OpenMe.txt
Transferring file from 73.138.32.5 to localhost...
File transfer complete!
 $ logout
Goodbye!
=== END TERMINAL LOG ===
 $ ls
folders:
  corn
files:
  New Document (16).docx.pdf
  nevergonnagive.mp4
  OpenMe.txt
 $ cat OpenMe.txt

   ***   ***     msg  = happy(day.valentines)
  *   * *   *    from = you.bestie
 *     *     *   to   = you
*             *  send(msg=msg, from=from, to=to)
 *           *
  *         *
   *       *
    *     *
     *   *
      * *
       *
 $ send_email --to gamer256@servmail.net --body “<3 U 2 :)”
Message Successfully Sent!
 $ logout
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: the output below, as returned by my terminal in color with --word-diff]

Text version:

```
Query-Logs:~$ get diff
diff --git a/original-doc.txt b/modified-doc.txt
index d910b07..6e1a64e 100644
--- a/original-doc.txt
+++ b/modified-doc.txt
@@ -1,19 +1,19 @@
where to buy {+toilet+} paper[-lanterns-]

how to make hand [-made lasagna-]{+sanitizer+}

[-most popular restaurants-]{+is it safe to go out+} for dinner[-parties-]

[-suit-]cases per [-days of vacation-]{+100 thousand+}

how to [-use vr-]{+wear mask+} with glasses

how to fix [-car makes rumbling-]{+zoom has no+} sound

how to [-rake in-]{+know if a+} cold [-hard cash-]{+is a symptom+}

[-personality-]{+rapid+} test

[-bars-]{+how+} to get [-tequila-]{+booster+} shots

when will this [-season start-]{+be over+}
```